# How to show API error handle inside of react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, api, error-handling, postman

In login, if email & password are empty, it throws an error like this:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "email": "please enter valid emails",
        "password": "please enter password"
    }
}
```

On API/login I send:

```
 {
    "email":"",
    "password":""
}
```

And i want to show this error in my React.js front end so I try this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import AppIcon from '../images/icon.png'
//mivi stuff
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import  Typography  from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import axios from 'axios';




class login extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state ={
            email:'',
            password:'',
            loading:false,
            error: {}

        }
    }
    handleChnage = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
       // console.log('hi');
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            loading:true
        });
        const userData ={
            email:this.state.email,
            password:this.state.password
        }
        axios.post('/login', userData)
        .then((res) =>{
            //console.log(res.data)
            this.setState({
                loading:false
            });
            this.props.history.push('/');
        })
        .catch((err) =>{
            this.setState({
                errors:err.response.data,   
                loading:false
            })
        })
    }
    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;
        const {error ,loading} = this.state
        return (
           <Grid container className={classes.form}>
                <Grid item sm />
                <Grid item sm >
                   <img src={AppIcon} alt="app cion" className={classes.image}/> 
                   <Typography variant="h2" className={classes.pagetitle}>Login</Typography>  
                   <form noValidate onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <TextField id="email" name="email" type="email" label="Email" className={classes.textfeild}
                         helperText={error.email} error={error.email ? true : false}  value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChnage} fullWidth />
                        <TextField id="password" name="password" type="password" label="Password" className={classes.textfeild}
                            helperText={error.password} error={error.password ? true : false}    value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChnage} fullWidth />
                        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>Login </Button>
                   </form>
                 </Grid>
                <Grid item sm />
           </Grid>
        )
    }
}

login.propTypes ={
classes:PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(styles)(login);
```

When username and password are empty and when I click, those errors are not showing. How can i fix this?

Because of the API errors are inside of errors' object, i hope that's why it is not showing, but I can't change this back and I want to show if email or password empty. I want to show that error here:

In side of `helperText={error.email} helperText={error.password}`

Comment: Try `console.log(err.response.data)` in catch and check if you are getting correct format.

Comment: yep iam getting ```errors: {…}
​​
email: "please enter valid emails"
​​
password: "please enter password"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state has `error` and you are trying to assign the value to `errors`, you need to set state to `error`. Because you are using `error.email` and `error.password` to show error.

```
.catch((err) =>{
     this.setState({
         error:err.response.data,   
         loading:false
     })
})
```

**Update**

As you are getting this as a result of `err.response.data`,

> errors: Object { email: "please enter valid emails", password: "please enter password" }

You need to access `errors` from `err.response.data` like,

```
.catch((err) =>{
     this.setState({
         error:err.response.data.errors,   
         loading:false
     })
})
```

Comment: i try but not show error my consul log  ```errors: Object { email: "please enter valid emails", password: "please enter password" } ```

Comment: In your render method try to print error and check what you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Update Your `.catch` block as

```
.catch((err) =>{
       const { errors } = err.response.data;
        this.setState({
            errors,   
            loading:false
        })
    })
```

Comment: This comment isn't really helpful, what doesn't work ?